# CSS beginning writing code

Tags: css

Hi for the last couple of weeks ive tryed learning CSS with some CSS3 elements that curent work on some browsers.I know what every element those and how to use them in very basic examples and I even managed to build a basic website using only CSS2 elements.

My question is what should i do next  to improve my skills there are tons of sites on the internet that have some interesting ways of using CSS but there very complex and I have a hard time understanting it(in most case I dont't)?

Can you guys provide me with some links or a book that will help me improve my skills?

Answer (score 2):

Google W3C - this is a good place to start.

After that http://www.css-tricks.com, http://www.csswizardry.com, http://www.nettuts.com

Answer (score 0):

You learn by doing, so just give yourself a nice assignment like: make a three column layout using only divs contained in a wrapper div (with a bg colour) and make sure the containing div scales with your three divs. Style each div and fill it with different content.

Then use the W3C validator and w3c css validator to see how well you performed :D

Gr.

Comment: I've done simple practices like that and validating I have no problem in working with a couple of elements and even building a basic website what I want to learn is more advanced stuff

Comment: How advanced do you want to go in CSS, its all pretty easy :D It never becomes rocket science. Are you referring to "advanced" things like float, overflow, clear etc... Or do you mean "advanced" things like box-shadow or I liquid layouts? Its best you start learning Javascript or PHP or something

Comment: I know how to use every element in css but sometimes have troubles with some of them when implementing I probably need mroe practice but dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I found an earlier version of this book to be a great help when I started:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/HTML-XHTML-CSS-Visual-QuickStart/dp/0321430840/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1315311880&sr=8-15